# How to remove background color from list items on a twitter bootstrap button dropdown menu?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am struggling with the button dropdowns, I cannot remove the blue background color that appears when hovering through the menu list items. I tried changing the a:hover CSS but with no success. Maybe this background color is dinamically added with javascript?

Thanks!

**Edit**:

I tried this code and no success:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
      .dropdown > li > a:hover {
          background-color: transparent;   
      }
    </style>

    <div class="btn-group">
      <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
        Action
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">link me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link me too</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

It looks like the CSS background color is not applied to the  element. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work

```
.dropdown-menu li a:hover :focus {
    color:black;/*color turns white if not changed*/
    background: none;           
}
```

Comment: it does not work. Look my edited question, where I try your CSS with no success...

Comment: Fixed and tested, just change the color to  whatever you need

Comment: I know it is old, but I needed to use this code and I found out that you should apply this style to the :focus selector too.